# Cannot open Local Terminal Failed to start [cmd.exe] in C:/Users/Home/PycharmProjects/untitled in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

i can't use terminal in PyCharm, i saw a lot of submissions about this problem but there's no clear answer, and most of them are "your antivirus's blocking cmd for PyCharm" (or something like that), but **i don't use any**. also i'm on Windows 7 i don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: If it isn't an antivirus, could it be your firewall?

Comment: i turned it on there too

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Settings > Terminal and change shell path from powershell.exe to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe.

This fixed the issue.